# Pointer increment in array struct in C

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, struct, auto-increment

I'm currently trying to do project that consists of creating a program that helps to manage a fleet of eletric vehicles. In this program, the fleet can only have a maximum of 10 vehicles. These vehicles have data that the user will write (vehicle identification, available battery, registration date, etc). So I made a structure for each vehicle, therefore making a array of 10 for that struct. One of the features was something I described earlier: "Register new vehicle" - the user will input some data in order to register a new vehicle.

I dont understand much of pointers, since I haven't wrote almost any code using them, but I'm trying to make the pointer `pCar` to increment and therefore, store another value. The problem is that the increment isn't working as intented, and it's just overwriting the same array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct InfoCar
{
    char CarID[9];
}Car[10], *pCar = NULL;

void copystring(char *copyfromhere, char *copytohere);

void copystring(char *copyfromhere, char *copytohere)
{
    while(*copytohere != '\0'){
            *copyfromhere = *copytohere;
    ++copytohere;
    ++copyfromhere;
}
}

void RegisterNewCar()
{
    pCar = Car;
   char aux[9];

        printf("\nCar ID: ");
        scanf("%s", aux);

        if(strcmp(aux, pCar->CarID) == 0)
        {
            system("cls");
            printf("Car ID already registered.");
            RegisterNewCar();
        }

       else {
            copystring(aux, pCar->CarID);
            pCar++;
           }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but with the assignment `*copyfromhere = *copytohere` the variable names doesn't make much sense.

Comment: More related to your problem, each time you call `RegisterNewCar` you do `pCar = Car` which makes it point to `Car[0]`. You can increment `pCar` as much as you want, but next call to `RegisterNewCar` will reset it back to point to `Car[0]`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude not using that var in original code, since English is not my first language I just did a quick translate in order to help the read.

Comment: Also: `strcmp(aux, pCar->CarID)` seems like a bad idea since `pCar->CarID` might not be initialized and have *indeterminate* (read: garbage) contents and very likely not be null-terminated leading to *undefined behavior* as there's a chance `strcmp` goes out of bounds.

Comment: *Furthermore* your recursion makes no sense. Why not use a loop? Then you don't even need the `pCar` variable just a plain integer for the index into the `Car` array.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks for the tips. In the original code I used an integer and a loop as you said, but as I moved forward and tried to code another feature (the battery percentage), there was a problem with the values stored. The input is made in the function `RegisterNewCar` and then in other functions I'll need some of the values that were stored in the `RegisterNewCar`. Basically, function A reads the data from the cars and function B, C, etc., use that data. Since I was already having issues with some stored data, I tried to use pointers to access them directly in memory.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you use a pointer or an index into your array. You must use a loop to search your array. Recursion will not do the trick as you need to input the ID again and again. Also your `copystring` function is weird. You switch meaning of `fromHere` and `toThere` which means you actually copy from `pCar->CarID` into `aux` instead of the other way around.